# jqGrid error when setting width using new API

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using the new API to set the width of my jqGrid like this:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(window).width() * 0.98);
```

The problem is that in IE7 I'm getting this error:

*'p.cellLayout' is null or not an object*

This only happens in IE7 (IE8, Firefox and Chrome work fine). Has anybody else encounter this problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you try to use `setGridWidth` function on the wrong place. I would recommend you to place this call inside of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete` event.

**UPDATED**: I have no IE7, so I can not test this problem. There are parameter `cellLayout` of jqGrid which has default value 5 and is documented on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options. This parameter are used inside of `setGridWidth` function. If is not clear you me why this parameter should be `null`, but you can verify this before calling of `setGridWidth`. The construct `alert($('#grid')[0].p.cellLayout);` will show you this value. You can try to set this value to 5 before calling of `setGridWidth`, but if you really have this property as `null`, you have definitively a problem somewhere else.

In all situations like your problem it is always good to post a code example in your question, so that other could reproduce your problem. Sometimes you have a real problem not on the place which you describe. So a code example is always very helpful.

Comment: Actually, I'm calling this method from the gridComplete event

Comment: Just found that there was another call to that method before the gridComplete event. I removed it and it's now working. Thanks!